# How to read csv file stored as an artifact in MLrun

Tags: python, amazon-s3, mlrun

I am  new  to `MLRun` . Facing below issue
In `MLrun` , I have saved my artifact (csv file) using the mlrun context .

```
context.log_artifact(TableArtifact('mydf', df=dataset, visible=True))
```

Now I wanted to read the csv file some other function .How can I  read that artifact .
When I saved the artifact it is getting stored into the s3 Bucket.
for example :

```
s3://mlrun/projects/test-pipeline/artifacts/data-prep-test-data-generator/0/mydf.csv
```

is it possible to read from that path.
When i am trying to access it directly using `pd.read_csv("s3://mlrun/projects/test-pipeline/artifacts/data-prep-test-data-generator/0/mydf.csv")`

it is telling this bucket doesn't exist.
Is there any `MLrun` api to read this file . I could not find any .

Comment: Are you sure it's saying that the bucket doesn't exist? Or just that whole path? Pandas cannot directly read S3 files, last I checked. You'd have to download it first using boto3

Comment: Thanks for response Yes it is giving the bucket does not exist error . I am not sure if i am doing it in correct way . I create artifact using context.log_artifact(TableArtifact('mydf', df=dataset, visible=True)) in mlrun function. Just wanted to access this saved artifact in the code without downloadin

Comment: Is there any MLrun api to access , I Can read trainer_run.artifact("mydf").as_df().head() like this .Trainer_run is my MLrun handler function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the below solution .

```
mlrun.get_dataitem('s3://mlrun/projects/{project_name}-jovyan/artifacts/trainer-train/0/mydf.csv').as_df()
```

Project_name is MLRun project name